# Save Instance in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-savedstate

I have a Fragment called HomeFragment.java. This is the first fragment that is launched when my app is opened. Inside this fragment, I have a method called "onAsyncTaskDoInBackground" that gets all the data from the server using JSON.

What i am trying to do is use "savedInstanceState" so that every time the "HomeFragment.java" is reopened not to re-download all the data.

Example:

The user opens the app and the Homefragment.java is launched, all the data is downloaded. The user goes to the about us page and returns to the Home page (Homefragment,java) all the data is downloaded again. (There should be no need to re-download all the data on the same app launch)

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener, MainActivity.OnLocationListener {

private View viewInflate;
DisplayImageOptions options;
ArrayList<Store> storeList;
ArrayList<News> newsList;
private ArrayList<News> arrayData;
MGAsyncTask task;
Queries q;
private Store store;
Random rand = new Random();


public HomeFragment() { }

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    viewInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    return viewInflate;


}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
}



@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .showImageOnFail(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
    newsList = new ArrayList<News>();

    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    timer();
    main.showSwipeProgress();
    main.getDebugKey();


    q = main.getQueries();
    if(MGUtilities.isLocationEnabled(getActivity())) {
        if(MainActivity.location == null) {
            main.setOnLocationListener(this);
        }
        else {
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getData();
                    arrayData  = q.getNews();
                }
            }, Config.DELAY_SHOW_ANIMATION);
        }
    }
    else {
        main.setOnLocationListener(this);
    }
}


public void getData() {
    task = new MGAsyncTask(getActivity());

    task.setMGAsyncTaskListener(new OnMGAsyncTaskListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskProgressUpdate(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPreExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            asyncTask.dialog.hide();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPostExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            arrayData  = q.getNews();
            if(!MGUtilities.hasConnection(getActivity())) {
                ArrayList<Store> stores = q.getStoresFeatured();
                ArrayList<News> news = q.getNews();
                if (Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT != -1 && Config.RANK_STORES_ACCORDING_TO_NEARBY) {
                    Log.v("myApp", "STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - " );

                    int storeCount = stores.size() < Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT ?
                            stores.size() : Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT;

                    if (MainActivity.location != null) {
                        for (Store store : stores) {
                            Location locStore = new Location("Store");
                            locStore.setLatitude(store.getLat());
                            locStore.setLongitude(store.getLon());
                            double userDistanceFromStore = MainActivity.location.distanceTo(locStore) / 1000;
                            store.setDistance(userDistanceFromStore);
                        }

                        Collections.sort(stores, new Comparator<Store>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Store store, Store t1) {
                                if (store.getDistance() < t1.getDistance())
                                    return -1;
                                if (store.getDistance() > t1.getDistance())
                                    return 1;
                                return 0;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
                    for (int x = 0; x < storeCount; x++) {

                        storeList.add(stores.get(x));

                    }
                } else {
                    storeList = stores;
                }

                if (Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT != -1 && Config.RANK_STORES_ACCORDING_TO_NEARBY) {
                    Log.v("myApp", "NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - " );

                    int newsCount = news.size() < Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT ? news.size() : Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT;
                    newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
                    for (int x = 0; x < newsCount; x++) {
                        newsList.add(news.get(x));
                    }
                } else {
                    newsList = news;
                }
            }

            MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            main.hideSwipeProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if( MGUtilities.hasConnection(getActivity()) && MainActivity.location != null) {
                try {
                    UserAccessSession accessSession = UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity());
                    String strUrl = "";

                    if(accessSession.getFilterDistance() == 0) {
                        Log.v("myApp", "STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - " );
                        if(MGUtilities.hasConnection(getActivity())) {

                            try {

                                strUrl = String.format("%s?api_key=%s",
                                        Config.GET_CATEGORIES_JSON_URL,
                                        Config.API_KEY);

                                DataParser parser = new DataParser();
                                Data data = parser.getData(strUrl);

                                MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                                if (main == null)
                                    return;

                                Queries q = main.getQueries();
                                if (data == null)
                                    return;

                                q.deleteTable("categories");
                                if (data.getCategories() != null && data.getCategories().size() > 0) {
                                    Log.v("myApp", "CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - " );

                                    for (Category cat : data.getCategories()) {
                                        q.insertCategory(cat);
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        strUrl = String.format("%s?api_key=%s&lat=%f&lon=%f&radius=%f&news_count=%d&featured_count=%d&default_store_count_to_find_distance=%d",
                                Config.GET_HOME_STORES_NEWS_JSON_URL,
                                Config.API_KEY,
                                MainActivity.location.getLatitude(),
                                MainActivity.location.getLongitude(),
                                accessSession.getFilterDistance(),
                                Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT,
                                Config.HOME_FEATURED_COUNT,
                                Config.DEFAULT_STORE_COUNT_TO_FIND_DISTANCE);
                    }
                    else {

                        strUrl = String.format("%s?api_key=%s&lat=%f&lon=%f&radius=%f&news_count=%d&default_store_count_to_find_distance=%d",
                                Config.GET_HOME_STORES_NEWS_JSON_URL,
                                Config.API_KEY,
                                MainActivity.location.getLatitude(),
                                MainActivity.location.getLongitude(),
                                accessSession.getFilterDistance(),
                                Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT,
                                Config.DEFAULT_STORE_COUNT_TO_FIND_DISTANCE);
                    }

                    DataParser parser = new DataParser();
                    Data data = parser.getData(strUrl);
                    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                    if (main == null)
                        return;

                    Queries q = main.getQueries();
                    if (data == null)
                        return;

                    if(Config.AUTO_ADJUST_DISTANCE) {
                        if(data.getMax_distance() > 0) {
                            UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity()).setFilterDistanceMax(data.getMax_distance());
                        }

                        if(UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity()).getFilterDistance() == 0) {
                            UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity()).setFilterDistance(data.getDefault_distance());
                        }
                    }



                    if (data.getStores() != null && data.getStores().size() > 0) {
                        Log.v("myApp", "ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF" );

                        int storeCount = data.getStores().size() < Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT ?
                                data.getStores().size() : Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT;

                        int x = 0;
                        for (Store store : data.getStores()) {
                            Location locStore = new Location("Store");
                            locStore.setLatitude(store.getLat());
                            locStore.setLongitude(store.getLon());
                            double userDistanceFromStore = MainActivity.location.distanceTo(locStore) / 1000;
                            store.setDistance(userDistanceFromStore);
                            if (userDistanceFromStore < 50){
                                Log.v("myApp", "STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE- STORE" );
                                q.deleteStore(store.getStore_id());
                                q.insertStore(store);


                                if(x < storeCount) {
                                    Log.v("myApp", "if(x < storeCount) - if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)" );

                                    if (store.getFeatured() == 3 ) {
                                        storeList.add(store);
                                        x += 1;

                                    }


                                }

                                if (store.getPhotos() != null && store.getPhotos().size() > 0) {
                                    Log.v("myApp", "PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS" );
                                    for (Photo photo : store.getPhotos()) {
                                        q.deletePhoto(photo.getPhoto_id());
                                        q.insertPhoto(photo);
                                    }
                                }
                            }}


                        if (data.getNews() != null && data.getNews().size() > 0) {
                            Log.v("myApp", "NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS" );
                            int newsCount = data.getNews().size() < Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT
                                    ? data.getNews().size() : Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT;

                            x = 0;
                            for (News news : data.getNews()) {
                                q.deleteNews(news.getNews_id());
                                q.insertNews(news);

                                if(x < newsCount) {
                                    newsList.add(news);
                                    x += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }}

                    try {
                        strUrl = "";
                        strUrl = String.format("%s?api_key=%s",
                                Config.GET_NEWS_JSON_URL,
                                Config.API_KEY);
                        Log.v("myApp", "NEWS UPDATE - NEWS UPDATE - NEWS UPDATE - NEWS UPDATE - NEWS UPDATE - NEWS UPDATE - NEWS UPDATE " );

                        parser = new DataParser();
                        data = parser.getData(strUrl);
                        main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                        if (main == null)
                            return;


                        if (data == null)
                            return;

                        q.deleteTable("news");
                        if (data.getNews() != null && data.getNews().size() > 0) {
                            for (News news : data.getNews()) {
                                q.insertNews(news);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    task.execute();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()  {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (viewInflate != null) {
        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) viewInflate.getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null) {
            MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
            slider.pauseSliderAnimation();
            parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
}
Handler handler = new Handler();
int apple = 0;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(apple < 5) {
            timer();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    slider.stopSliderAnimation();
    switch(v.getId()) { }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    slider.resumeSliderAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    slider.pauseSliderAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location prevLoc, Location currentLoc) {
    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    main.setOnLocationListener(null);
    getData();
}

}
```

Comment: everytime your onViewCreated is called it starts to load data. so, you can use a simple boolean flag for it and prevent future data load

Comment: Thanks but does not work, it showed no content on the Home screen

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like below.

```
private View viewFragment;
private ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    initIds();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // get all data and saved in list.
    } else {
        // use saved list or other data here...
        list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
        setListAdapter(list);
    }

    return viewFragment;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("arraylist", list);
}
```

Comment: I tried to add this code but kept getting multiple errors.

Comment: @QuickyApp make `MyClass implements Parcelable` it will work

Comment: Thanks for the help Akash i really apriciate it but its still not working. I get the error "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found:'java.until.Arraylist<com.models.Store>',required:'java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.osParcelabe>'"

Comment: If you have some free time could you add me on skype brunoalbu@outlook.com.br,
thanks

Comment: @QuickyApp post your Store class.

Comment: i added the store class

Comment: @QuickyApp you are implementing `Serializable` not `Parcelable`. check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32177307/3425390) and its comment for creating modal class.